# Hibernate - SQLServer - Connection reset. How to reestablish?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

My Spring Boot application works like this:

```
for(Stuff stuff : stuffList)
  {
    try(Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
      doStuff(stuff);
    } catch(Exception e) {
    ???
    }
  }
```

It's triggered periodically. The sessions I open are for SQLServer. "Stuff" is a set of data, usually small, but some are really big. The application works well, except this one time I found an exception in the logs. It occured during processing one of the big sets of data - the operation had been running for ~77 minutes at the time. Said exception is: `SQLServerException: Connection reset`, caused by `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`. I cannot reproduce it, so I'm not sure whether the fault is on the client's or the server's side. But it doesn't even matter to me right now - I need to know how to reestablish the connection so that the operations may continue without restarting the whole application, since after the original exception is thrown by `doStuff()`, every subsequent iteration of the loop - which uses fresh sessions - throws `SQLServerException: The connection is closed`. Or - does the application eventually reestablish the connection by itself?